# Dashboards de usuários logados utilizando user do django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Bom Dia
Estou utilizando o model de users padrão do Django, e gostaria de ter um dashboard de usuários logados, para verificar quem esta utilizando o sistema, sabem me informar se o django possui essa informação?

Eu verifiquei que possuem uma tabela de sessões mas esta tudo criptografado.

Desde já obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um método assíncrono, você pode registrar em um modelo próprio tanto o *login* quanto o *logout* do usuário, salvando esta informação antes de chamar as funções `login()` (registra que o usuário entrou) e `logout()` (registra que os usuário saiu) durante o processo de autenticação.

Answer (score 1):

Que eu veja dá pra fazer isso de duas formas:

1. Salvar alguma informação dos clientes atualmente ativos no banco de dados
2. Utilizar javascript para fornecer esses dados em tempo real

### 1º Opção

Esses links para pesquisa podem te ajudar nesse quesito:

- [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) - Fornece uma maneira de observar certos acontecimentos como o loggin e o logout
- Link com um exemplo da funcionalidade que vc queira executar(Obs.: Exemplo de código não tão recente. Talvez seja necessário realizar mudanças em relação a versão do código): [Exemplo do Django Signals](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2808/)

### 2º Opção

Javascript atualmente fornece API's para aplicações que necessitam de funcionalidades que se comunicam em tempo real e talvez seja outra possibilidade de resolver seu problema fazendo alguma verificação quando o usuário logar e o javascript comunicar isso ao backend.

- Biblioteca que pode ser útil: [Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)
- Exemplo de implementação da comunicação em tempo real(Obs.: está com o backend em Node.js mas a lógica talvez de dê uma luz): [Exemplo de comunicação em tempo real](https://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-de-chat-simples-com-nodejs-e-socket-io/))